# Concatenate column values into a new column based off value in another column

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, conditional-formatting

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
Item    Balance    Date
 1       200000    1/1/2020
 1       155000    2/1/2020
 1       100000    3/1/2020
 1        25000    4/1/2020
 1            0    5/1/2020 
 2       100000    1/1/2020 
 2        15000    2/1/2020
 2            0    3/1/2020
```

I would like to change the dataframe to the following format:

```
Item   Cycle
 1     4;2#01/01/2020;1000#02/01/2020;775#03/01/2020;500#04/01/2020;125#05/01/2020;0
 2     2;2#01/01/2020;1000#02/01/2020;150#03/01/2020;0
```

The cycle column will take the form of the count of non zero values (Balance field) for each item (there are 4 for item 1 and 2 for item 2) followed by a ; a constant of 2 followed by a # the date in the date column with an initial scaled value of 1000. Then # + (the next date value) + (current balance of item / initial balance of item) * initial scaled balance (1000) until the item observation reaches a balance of 0. When the item balance is 0; the cycle variable will close with #(date in date column);0. Please also note that the date will take the form of mm/dd/yyyy inside the cycle variable.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Date` column is already converted to `datetime64`:

```
def summarize(group):
    # The number of line items where Balance > 0
    count = (group['Balance'] > 0).sum()

    # Scale the data where the initial balance = 1000
    scaled = pd.DataFrame({
        'Balance': group['Balance'] / group['Balance'].iloc[0] * 1000,
        'Date': group['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    })

    # The lambda to produce the string 01/01/2020;1000
    f = lambda row: f'{row["Date"]};{row["Balance"]:.0f}'

    # Join the balances togather
    data = '#'.join(scaled.apply(f, axis=1))

    # The final string for each group
    return f'{count};2#{data}'

df.groupby('Item').apply(summarize)
```